# Angular test for component that makes an API call every 2 seconds and repeats upto x number of times until it finds a record

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I have a component where I make an API call repeatedly every 2 seconds and when the response contains a record with name = 'somename', I stop looping it by calling unsubscribe. Until, I find the record I need, I continue looping it, until
I reach a mazRetries count = 120. Here is my component code that
does this:

```
ngOnit() {
    this.retryCount = 0;
    this.maxRetries = 120;
    const source = interval(2000);
    this.subscription = source.subscribe(val => this.poll());
  }

  poll() {
    if (this.retryCount > this.maxRetries) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      return;
    }
    const myList = this.service.getRecords();
    console.log('myList = ' + myList);   // prints undefined when running my test below
    if (myList.length > 0) {
      const rec = myList.filter(v => v.name === 'somename');
      if (rec.length > 0) {
        window.location.href = rec.pop().url;   // redirect to an external url
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        return;
      }
    }
    this.retryCount++;
  }
```

Now, I am having difficulty testing out the code above. First, my spyOn below to return some mock date using `spyOn(myService, 'getRecords').and.callFake(() => records.slice())` does not seem to work when this code is wrapped in a timer.
I always use this style to mock response for the API calls that work perfectly, but when this call is running within a interval(2000).subscriber(.....), it does not work, and the response is undefined. I am not sure how to modify my test code so that it correctly returns the mocked response instead of undefined.

Plus, in my case, when the record I am looking for is found, I simply redirect to an external URL. This is a problem for the test as it will just halt once it goes to an external url. Is there a way I can tackle this issue, either by mocking this call or some other way ?

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  ..
  ..
  let myService;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent ],
      imports: [ UIRouterTestingModule ],
      providers: [
       MockMyServiceProvider
       ..
       ..
      ],
    })
      .compileComponents();

    let records = [{
      "name": "somename",
      "first": "firstname",
      "last": "lastname"
    }];

    myService = TestBed.inject(MyService);
    spyOn(myService, 'getRecords').and.callFake(() => records.slice());

  }));
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('component should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/retrywhen

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/repeat

Comment: You can use fakeAsync and tick, where you can specify the time to wait with tick(2000).